# How to create a package with the isolatedModules=true option enabled?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, create-react-app

In a file where I export all the classes of my package on lines like the following:

```
export {default as BoundList, IBoundListOption, TBoundListFilterFn} from './list/BoundList';
```

errors of the form are generated:

```
TS1205: Cannot re-export a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.
```

How do I export classes now?

This problem occurred in CRA2.1. There was forced to isolatedModules=true.
I'm making a component library on CRA2.1

Comment: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/603 Looks like there's some discussion here that includes workarounds.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CRA [v3.4.1](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v3.4.1) facilitates type re-exports under [`--isolatedModules`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). The contained [`@babel/preset-typescript`](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/11171) in version `v7.9.0`+  (see corresponding [Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v7.9.0) release and [announcement](https://babeljs.io/blog/2020/03/16/7.9.0.html#typescript-38-type-only-imports-and-exports-11171-https-githubcom-babel-babel-pull-11171)) and TypeScript support TS 3.8 [type-only imports and exports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export). You can now write:

```
export type { MyListType } from "./list/BoundList"

// or
import type { MyListType } from "./list/BoundList"
export type { MyListType }
// note additional "type" keyword
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728230/cannot-re-export-a-type-when-using-the-isolatedmodules-with-ts-3-2-2/59600601#59600601) for more info on the `import`/`export` syntax.

Answer (score 10):

[github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/603](http://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/603) (thanks to [@CollinD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5298696/collind) for the link) includes a workaround for how to re-export imported types. [This comment](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/603#issuecomment-418472968) on that issue has the best explanation of a workaround:

> You can still do are-export if it's clear that you're exporting a type:
>
> ```
> import { T as a_T } from "./a";
> export type T = a_T;
> ```
>
> You can also do `export * from "./a";`.

If I'm reading that GitHub issue correctly, only TS types can be re-exported, but values (e.g. classes) can't be re-exported. So if TS knows that you're importing a type (not a class) then you can re-export it.

Here's another example that's simpler:

```
import { T } from "./a";
export type T = T;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - `node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/package.json` is "version": "0.2.2".

It seems the change was made in **Microsoft/TypeScript#15538** , so if you test with 2.3 you wouldn't see the error. But it will start breaking when 2.4 is released.

Still, none of this should be an issue if isolatedModules is overriden to true.

Answer (score 0):

tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "isolatedModules": false,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Pls add some description/explanation to your answer and explain how it works and solves the problem.