# Cannot re-export a type when using the --isolatedModules with TS 3.2.2

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-4

I probably need to rethink the way we structure our React components. We are using the latest react-scripts that allow Typescript to be used and by default, the `isolatedModules` is being enabled which currently bugs me a bit.

We used to structure a component like this:

```
Component
|_ Component.tsx
|_ index.ts
|_ types.ts
```

- `Component.tsx` holds the actual component without declarations
- `index.ts` is just re-exporting everything so we can have a singular entry point and can do something like `import Component, { ComponentType } from '@/Component';`
- `types.ts` holds the actual type definitions and exports most or all of them.

So far so good and that works without the `isolatedModules`. However, we also export some of the type definitions, effectively re-exporting the interfaces that were specified within `Component/types.ts`. This won't work as TypeScript itself would not transpile the code any longer.

How can I re-export this without having a separate import statement going to `@/Component/types` (which might be actual the simpler way anyway)?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

#### TS 3.8+

You can use [type-only imports and exports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#-type-only-imports-and-export) with `--isolatedModules`:

```
// types.ts
export type MyType = { a: string; b: number; };
```

```
// main.ts 

// named import/export
import type { MyType } from './types'
export type { MyType }

// re-export
export type { MyType } from './types'

// namespace import
import type * as MyTypes from "./types";
export type RenamedType = MyTypes.MyType;
export { MyTypes };

//     ^ Note the "type" keyword in statements above
```

[Example Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAECcFMFpIDwA4HtwBcBQ9ltKgngpKAN6gBiArgHYDGqAlklQMJIC2yVkVqoAvqABm4dqABEUAIZ0x6dCFBVJbSABNQ9DilTAs29Juy98hEqFZauPACoEiA4aImRpqWXpwmipC526pbUz45BSUVAGcEaSJDfVjPO1AAKlBJcNAAJRc6QMh0xzZxKRl0L1BrAEZQAF5M7IC7cIA6MmYgA); Take a look at the [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/35200) for possible extension forms and proposals.

---

#### TS 3.7 or older

In previous versions, the following is not possible:

```
import { MyType } from './types'; 
export { MyType }; // error: Cannot re-export a type with --isolatedModules

export { MyType } from "./types"; // error, like above
```

Type re-exports have to use a [workaround](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/603#issuecomment-418472968):

```
import { MyType as MyType_ } from "./types";
export type MyType = MyType_;

// or
export * from "./types"
```

Comment: Note: Above feature is supported in Babel starting with [v7.9.0](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v7.9.0)

Answer (score 8):

I am using the same structure personally and stumbled into the same issue after moving to a `create-react-app` boilerplate which enforces `isolatedModules`. A workaround that seems to be working in stark contrast to the idea behind `isolatedModules` is to use `export * from "./Component";` in `index.ts`.