# Export a type after its declaration on Typescript 3.8+

Tags: typescript, export

When trying to export a type after its declaration with Typescript 3.8+:

```
type Type = { Prop: string };
export { Type }
```

... VS Code gives the following error:

> Re-exporting a type when the `--isolatedModuls` flag is provided requires using `export type`

So I did as the error suggests:

```
type Type = { Prop: string };
export type { Type }
```

However, that caused another error, emitted by eslint:

> Parsing error: Declaration or statement expected.

2 questions:

1. Why is it considered "re-exporting"?
2. Isn't this kind of export allowed on Typescript 3.8+, with `--isolatedModuls` flag on, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59600601/3002584)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem:

1. When the `--isolatedModuls` flag is on, [VS Code's TypeScript language service](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_compiler-versus-language-service) can't tell if the type we're trying to export originated in the current module or not.

   There is a similar [Babel Github issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6065), where it is explained:

   > In order to determine whether something is a type, we need information
   > about other modules.
   >
   > ```js
   > import { T } from "./other-module";
   > export { T }; // Is this a type export?
   > ```

   There's also a great elaborated explanation on [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/e9span/isolatedmodules_prevents_exporting_a_type_from_a/):

   > type space is TypeScript's domain: all of the types that make up your
   > app. They only exist at compile time. Once the compiler is done, the
   > resulting JavaScript has no types left in it. Value space is basically
   > the opposite: it's the stuff that sticks around and survives into the
   > JS.
   >
   > ```js
   > type Foo = { bar: string };
   > const a: Foo = { bar: 'hello' };
   > ```
   >
   > Here, `Foo` is in the type space,
   > everything else is in the value space.
   >
   > The problem with `isolatedModules`, is they can't know which space they
   > are working with, since each file is compiled individually. So if you
   > do:
   >
   > ```js
   > export { Foo } from './bar';
   > ```
   >
   > in a file, TypeScript can't know if `Foo`
   > is in the type space (if it is, it just gets thrown away as it won't
   > be in the resulting JavaScript), or if it is in the value space (ie
   > it's JS, so it needs to be included in the resulting output).
2. As the error suggests, the way to do it is indeed:

   ```js
   type Type = { Prop: string };
   export type { Type }
   ```

   As described in my question, that caused an error emitted by eslint, but that error was actually wrong. I couldn't get that error go away, and eventually recreated my Typescript app, which succeeded.
   So for future readers, make sure you follow the correct installation:

   ```
   // the following creates a typescript app, and installs required type declarations, 
   // which are: @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
   npx create-react-app hello-world --template typescript

   // you'd probably work with react-redux, so install it as follows:
   cd hello-world
   npm install --save redux @types/redux
   npm install --save react-redux @types/react-redux
   ```

   As for eslint, the eslint module for Typescript, which is called [*@typescript-eslint*](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint), should be installed under node_modules after following the above steps. You can verify that by decalring an unused variable:

   ```js
   const a = 1;
   ```

   Which would cause @typescript-eslint to emit a warning:

   > 'a' is assigned a value but is never used

   P.S.

   Note that some errors are still emited by *eslint* itself, and not by *@typescript-eslint*. For example, try to incorrectly export the variable `a` we declared above, like so:

   ```js
   const a = 1;
   export a; // gives an error
   ```

   ... and you'll get the aforementioned Parsing Error emitted by eslint.